# How to get out a search result from forEach in an Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have a React app with some JSON data. I have a drop down menu to set a status to a job in my app. I have a state called status with loaded statuses with their ids as follows.

```
this.state.status: [
  {id: 1, name: 'To-do'},
  {id: 2, name: 'In-progress'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Completed'},
]
```

When change the status by selecting a menu item in the drop down list, I need to send the status id to the API. So I'm setting the value of the drop down list with selected status and find the status id by status name in the status Object and get the particular id. Here what I have tried so far. **The problem is, API call can't catch the status id. Console says "status_id is not defined"**

```
statusHandleChange = event => {
        const project_id = this.props.projectData.id;
        const job_id = this.props.projectData.currentJobId;

        this.setState({ currentStatus: event.target.value }, () =>
            Object.keys(this.state.status).forEach((key) => {
                if (this.state.status[key].name === event.target.value) {
                    const status_id = (this.state.status[key].id)
                }
            }),

            API.post('job/change_current_status', { project_id, job_id, status_id })
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    console.log("success!", data)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
                })
        );

    };
```

**ERROR : 'status_id' is not defined!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you defined `status_id` as a block-scoped constant inside an if statement inside a function - it's not accessible outside of that `if` statement. You can use `find` and `Object.values` with destructuring instead (because `forEach` doesn't return anything):

```
const { id: status_id } = Object.values(this.state.status).find(({ name }) => name === event.target.value);
```

Comment: It looks like he compares strings, so any reason for the double equals instead of tripple ones?

Comment: Whoops, sorry @wiesson, didn't see that in the OP's code, thanks for that.

Comment: I was just curious if it had a deeper meaning that I wasn't aware of :)

Comment: Nope @wiesson - strict equality `===` compares type and value - so `0 !== "0"`, but `0 === 0`. Equality `==` compares only value, not type, therefore it converts types - so `0 == "0"`, but `0 == false` too.